# Error: System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Tags: powershell, azure

While going through https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring at Local deployment and while debugging got an error:

**Error:**

```
At G:\Azure-IoT\2.Customize a preconfigured solution\Trail_1\azure-iot-remote-monitoring\Common\Deployment\DeploymentLib.ps1:704 char:23

+ $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "GET" -Uri $uri -Headers @{"Auth ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I am using Azure power shell 1.6.0 Version. 
Can anyone tell me what's going wrong ?

Comment: What's not clear in error description? Keywords: `ArgumentException`, `DeploymentLib.ps1:704 char:23`. Check arguments in the script on 704'th line.

Comment: Here is the 704th line $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "GET" -Uri $uri -Headers @{"Authorization"=$header;"Content-Type"="application/json"}

Comment: And what's in your `$header` variable?

Comment: Please check this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/blob/master/Common/Deployment/DeploymentLib.ps1

Comment: Solved, please check https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/issues/291